# View the state of a state machine workflow

Tags: workflow, state-machine

I created a state machine workflow (with off course different states) for a content type.

When i create a library with that content type and start the workflow. I can not see in which state i am.

Is this possible to view the state?

Comment: did you know answer to your question?

Comment: Nope, not yet..